# Create three tables with the same auto increment primary key and name

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2017

Cannot find a good answer for this online. I need to create three tables as an example below, a parent with an auto increment ID that will then link to the two child tables (Subject and Comment) with the same exact ID and cascade back if that parent ID is deleted.
Any ideas on how to solve?
I have googled and am extremely confused as to how to solve this one. I have a decent amount of experience with SQL, but not with creating tables and relationships.

```
CREATE TABLE Parent
(
    ParentID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    Email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,...
)

CREATE TABLE Subject
(
    ParentID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Subject
)

CREATE TABLE Comment
(
    ParentID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Comment VARCHAR(100)
)
```

Comment: you add a row to Parent, capture the ID and then insert into the 1-1 tables using that ID. Cascading deletes is rarely a good idea IMO. Better to control deletes through front end code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a 1 to 1 relationship with `on delete cascade`:

```
CREATE TABLE Parent(
    ParentID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    Email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,...
)

CREATE TABLE Subject(
    ParentID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Subject,
    CONSTRAINT fk_SubjectParentId FOREIGN KEY (ParentID)
    REFERENCES Parent (ParentID) ON DELETE CASCADE
)

CREATE TABLE Comment(
    ParentID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Comment VARCHAR(100),
    CONSTRAINT fk_CommentParentId FOREIGN KEY (ParentID)
    REFERENCES Parent (ParentID) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

This is known as a 1 to 1 relationship, since both ends of the foreign key are unique within their table.

Though I have to agree with Mitch Wheat comment, cascading deletes is something to use with caution. by specifying cascade delete, you are telling the database engine to delete the related records whenever a parent record is deleted. Not having that cascade delete option will simply throw an error if you attempt to delete a record that is referenced by another table. This forces you, as a developer, to think about the side effects of deleting rows from the parent table and basically acts as a "Are you sure you want to delete?" guard against unwanted deletes.

Comment: Yeah, too easy to makes 'oopsies' with cascade deletes. +1

Comment: Thanks Zohar! I really appreciate it. So just to clarify this should be fine if the field names are the same? I just saw another SO thread where someone was saying that it could cause issues

Comment: @mcgi906 not a problem at all, since each column is a member of a different table. The only thing to remember is that when selecting from both tables using a join you will need to use aliases to distinguish the different columns (not a problem in this case since only duplicated names are on the FK columns anyway...)

Comment: @MitchWheat My biggest "oopsie" ever: shift-delete the last backup of a production database, after deleting it from the old server, before restoring it to the new server, while  my boss sits in the chair next to me. Cascade deletes ain't got nothing on me :-)

Comment: @MitchWheat Yeah, that was one hell of a scary moment. In my defense it was 2 A.M and I was in the office since 7 A.M, and lucky for me, we had a back up from 30 minutes before, so we only lost a very small amount of data... On the plus side, I never shift delete again :-)